# Javascript calculations between text boxes

Tags: javascript, html

My Javascript function `aa()` is called with the value of the `paying_now` input field. I want to find the sum of the value of `paying_now` and of `paid`, and the difference of `balance` and `paying_now`.

The values of `netpay`, `balance`, and `paid` will be fetched from a database. Here, I have set `net_pay` to 1000, as an example.

This code works only with balance and doesn't change the `paid` textbox, when the `paying_now` value should be added to it. NaN is also occuring. What gives?

### Javascript

```
   function aa(paying_now)
    {
        var net_pay = document.getElementById('net_pay').value;

        var paid = document.getElementById('paid_hidden').value;
        var balance = document.getElementById('balance_hidden').value;

        if(parseInt(paying_now) > parseInt(net_pay))
        {
            document.getElementById('paying_now').value=0;
            document.getElementById('paid').value=paid;
            document.getElementById('balance').value=balance;
            alert("Amount Paying now cannot be higher than Netpay");
            return;
        }
        else if(parseInt(paying_now) > parseInt(balance))
        {
            document.getElementById('paying_now').value=0;
            document.getElementById('paid').value=paid;
            document.getElementById('balance').value=balance;
            alert("Amount Paying now cannot be higher than balance amount");
            return;

        }

    document.getElementById('paid').value = parseInt(paid)+parseInt(paying_now);
    document.getElementById('balance').value = parseInt(balance)-parseInt(paying_now);

    }
```

### HTML

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td>
            <strong>Netpay:</strong>
            <input type='text' id='net_pay' value = '1000' readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
            Paid: <input type='text' value='100' id='paid' name='paid' readonly />
            <input type='hidden' value='100' id='paid_hidden' ></td>
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>Balance:</strong>
            <input type='text' value='900' id='balance' readonly />
            <input type='hidden' value='900' id='balance_hidden' />
        </td>

        <td>
            <strong>Paying now:</strong><input type='text' id='paying_now' onkeyUp='aa(this.value);' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

For what it's worth, here is a JSFiddle with this code: http://jsfiddle.net/JeSZX/

Comment: Hi, your html looks extremly malformed. I have created jsfiddle to work with: http://jsfiddle.net/JeSZX/ - I try to find solution now

Comment: your script is working good even with paid box,NAN is coming when the paying text box has no value and in that case the parseInt() return NAN and with the paid value a string 'NAN' got added and than parse finally returns the NAN which represent not an number.

Comment: Cant edit my last comment - My prior jsfiddle was not working well, i modified it: http://jsfiddle.net/ZDKSe/

Comment: It works but, how can i avoid NaN in the fields ? its getting displayed when i make changes in that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have modified the code. Please implement this, its working fine.

```
function aa(paying_now)
{
    var net_pay = document.getElementById('net_pay').value;
    var paid = document.getElementById('paid_hidden').value;
    var balance = document.getElementById('balance_hidden').value;

    if(paying_now === ""){
        document.getElementById('paid').value = paid;
        document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
    }    
    else if(parseInt(paying_now) > parseInt(net_pay))
    {
        alert("Amount Paying now cannot be higher than Netpay");
        document.getElementById('paying_now').value="";
        document.getElementById('paid').value=paid;
        document.getElementById('balance').value=balance;
        document.getElementById('paying_now').focus();
    }
    else if(parseInt(paying_now) > parseInt(balance))
    {
        alert("Amount Paying now cannot be higher than balance amount");
        document.getElementById('paying_now').value="";
        document.getElementById('paying_now').focus();
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById('paid').value = parseInt(paid)+parseInt(paying_now);
    document.getElementById('balance').value = parseInt(balance)-parseInt(paying_now);
    }
}
```

There were some small mistakes in html code, please change that too. For example, in certain places closing tag were missing. Put the hidden field inside `<td>` and `</td>` only.

Comment: A friendly note for the future: it may help to explain what the original problem was and how you resolved it, rather than just provide a fix, so that such problems don't occur again for other people in similar situations.

Answer (score 3):

Your JScript code does basically what you described you want it to do (but maybe I've understood it wrong).

NaN is appearing whenever you have some values in your paying now-field which aren't numbers (p.e. nothing or letters). In order to counter this you need to check the content of the variable `paying_now` before doing some arithmetics with it, p.e. with the [`isNaN()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function:

```
if (isNaN(paying_now) == false) {
    alert ("Not a number!");
    return;
}
```

Your demo html code is slightly obfuscating the issues, echos and table construction isn't part of your problem.

Try simplyfing it slightly, something like this:

```
Netpay:
<input type='text' id='net_pay' value = '1000' readonly />
Paid:
<input type='text' value='100' id='paid' name='paid' readonly />
<input type='hidden' value='100' id='paid_hidden' />
Balance:
<input type='text' value='900' id='balance' readonly />
<input type='hidden' value='900' id='balance_hidden' />
Paying now:
<input type='text' id='paying_now' onkeyUp='aa(this.value);' />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>

<head>
<script>
function aa(paying_now)
    {

    if(isNaN(parseInt(paying_now)))
{paying_now=0;
}
    var net_pay = document.getElementById('net_pay').value;

        var paid = document.getElementById('paid_hidden').value;
        var balance = document.getElementById('balance_hidden').value;

        if(parseInt(paying_now) > parseInt(net_pay))
        {
            document.getElementById('paying_now').value=0;
            document.getElementById('paid').value=paid;
            document.getElementById('balance').value=balance;
            alert("Amount Paying now cannot be higher than Netpay");
            return;
        }
        else if(parseInt(paying_now) > parseInt(balance))
        {
            document.getElementById('paying_now').value=0;
            document.getElementById('paid').value=paid;
            document.getElementById('balance').value=balance;
            alert("Amount Paying now cannot be higher than balance amount");
            return;

        }

    document.getElementById('paid').value = parseInt(paid)+parseInt(paying_now);
    document.getElementById('balance').value = parseInt(balance)-parseInt(paying_now);

    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form1">

<table>
<tr><td>
<strong>
Netpay:<strong>
<input type='text' id='net_pay' value = '1000' readonly />
<td>Paid:<input type='text' value='100' id='paid' name='paid' readonly />
</td>
<input type='hidden' value='100' id='paid_hidden' >
<td><strong>Balance:</strong><input type='text' value='900' id='balance' readonly /></td>
<input type='hidden' value='900' id='balance_hidden' />
<td><strong>Paying now:</strong><input type='text' id='paying_now' onkeyUp='aa(this.value);' /></td></tr>

  </table>

</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

check out this its working fine for me , I have added the following line extra to your code for handling NaN like "" or alphabets

```
 if(isNaN(parseInt(paying_now)))
{paying_now=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if u want to get only current change value at paid you have to just remove the addition of 'paid ' and 'paying_now' so your code will look like.

```
<script>
function aa(paying_now)
{


    var net_pay = document.getElementById('net_pay').value;
    var pay_now=document.getElementById('paying_now').value;
    var paid = document.getElementById('paid_hidden').value;
    var balance = document.getElementById('balance_hidden').value;

    if(pay_now==" ")
    {
        alert("value requrie");
        document.getElementById('paying_now').focus();
        document.getElementById('paid_hidden').value=paid;
        document.getElementById('balance_hidden').value=balance;
        return;
    }

    if(parseInt(paying_now) > parseInt(net_pay))
    {
        document.getElementById('paying_now').value=0;
        document.getElementById('paid').value=paid;
        document.getElementById('balance').value=balance;
        alert("Amount Paying now cannot be higher than Netpay");
        return;
    }
    else if(parseInt(paying_now) > parseInt(balance))
    {
        document.getElementById('paying_now').value=0;
        document.getElementById('paid').value=paid;
        document.getElementById('balance').value=balance;
        alert("Amount Paying now cannot be higher than balance amount");
        return;

    }

document.getElementById('paid').value = parseInt(paying_now);
document.getElementById('balance').value = parseInt(balance)-parseInt(paying_now);

}
</script>
```

Comment: A friendly note for the future: it may help to explain what the original problem was and how you resolved it, rather than just provide a fix, so that such problems don't occur again for other people in similar situations.